# How to make the PhoneGap app's background transparent and revealing the current system wallpaper

Tags: android, cordova

Something I have done:

1.set the theme of the main activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"
```

2.set the background of the webview created by phoneGap

```
appView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

3.set the background of the body and html tag

```
html,
body{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

But, my app still has a black background, why ???

Comment: Try this http://www.41post.com/4213/programming/android-transparent-or-translucent-view-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    super.setIntegerProperty("backgroundColor", Color.TRANSPARENT);
    ...
}
```

Comment: where I can paste this?